# Вопрос по выборке в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Структура документов в коллекции такая:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("569190cd24de1e0ce2dfcd62"),
        "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
        "year" : 1982,
        "rated" : "PG",
        "released" : ISODate("1982-06-04T04:00:00Z"),
        "runtime" : 113,
        "countries" : [
                "USA"
        ],
        "awards" : {
                "wins" : 2,
                "nominations" : 9,
                "text" : "2 wins & 9 nominations."
        }
}
```

Пытаюсь получить содержимое конкретных полей используя проекцию и добавляя пару дополнительных параметров.
Хочу взять такие ключи `title`, `year`, `rated` и `awards`с указанными значениями. (_id убираю)

Прописываю так
`db.movieDetails.find( {}, {title: 1, year: 2013, rated: "PG-13", _id: 0, "awards.wins": 1 }).pretty()`, чтобы получить поля и со значениями, но в консоли выводит в разнобой:

```
{
        "title" : "Once Upon a Time in the West",
        "year" : 1968,
        "rated" : "PG-13",
        "awards" : {
                "wins" : 4
        }
}
{
        "title" : "A Million Ways to Die in the West",
        "year" : 2014,
        "rated" : "R",
        "awards" : {
                "wins" : 0
        }
}
{
        "title" : "Wild Wild West",
        "year" : 1999,
        "rated" : "PG-13",
        "awards" : {
                "wins" : 10
        }
}
```

А хотелось бы так:

```
 {
            "title" : "Once Upon a Time in the West",
            "year" : 2013,
            "rated" : "PG-13",
            "awards" : {
                    "wins" : 0
            }
    }
    {
            "title" : "A Million Ways to Die in the West",
            "year" : 2013,
            "rated" : "PG-13",
            "awards" : {
                    "wins" : 0
            }
    }
    {
            "title" : "Wild Wild West",
            "year" : 2013,
            "rated" : "PG-13",
            "awards" : {
                    "wins" : 0
            }
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно исправить в запросе, чтобы выводило под мои требования?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге [решилось](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825219/how-to-write-specific-query-in-mongodb)таким образом, в моем случае:

```
 db.movieDetails.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          title: 1,
          _id: 0,
          year: "2013",
          rated: "PG-13",
          "awards.wins": "0"
        }
      }
    ]).pretty()
```

Или так по конкретному запросу:

```
db.movieDetails.find({year : 2013, rated:"PG-13", "awards.wins": 0},{title: 1, year:1 , rated: 1, _id: 0,awards:1, "awards.wins": 1 }).pretty()
```